# Open a pyglet window without taking focus

Tags: python, windows, graphics, subprocess, pyglet

My python application launches a subprocess that creates a pyglet window. When the pyglet window opens, it is in front of all other windows, and takes keyboard focus. **I'd like my pyglet window to open in the background, and not take focus. Is this possible?**

Stripped-down version of the code I'm using:

```
import pyglet

pyglet.window.Window()
pyglet.app.run()
```

I'm using Windows 7, in case that makes a difference..

Comment: Giving it a second thought, you do have a weird case of popping up pyglet window w/o giving it the input. Maybe you actually need to learn how to embed OpenGL context of pyglet applet within your bigger application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reversing focus is OS specific:*

**pyglet** does not provide OS specific window control. So most likely you will have to use an ad-hoc trick for quick&dirty solutions or try to approach it with extensions like pywin32 using Windows API and/or COM to list through the stack of taskbar applications to reverse stealing of focus. You can also try to create your own window (container - which you can manipulate) first - in order to delegate its context to pyglet.

*Delaying stealing of focus*

On the other hand if according to your program logic you just want to delay actual showing of you application you can play with visibility:

```
import pyglet

w = pyglet.window.Window()
w.set_visible(False)
pyglet.app.run()
```

So if you don't want to play with delegation of window context, you can probably do the following:

1. start your application w/o showing the window
2. find the focus of the current active window by getting its handle/id
3. show your window
4. give back the focus to the previous window

The above assumes working with windows API. I think MSDN had examples on focus changing.. If you know PID of your current window (main application) this should simplify the step 2.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking this might be more of a windows / window manager issue than your app - will something like this http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/stealingfocus02.htm help ??